# error: expected expression before '?' token

Tags: c, conditional-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Enter Number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num % 2 == 0)? printf("Number is even"):printf("Number is odd");
}
```

In this ternary operation a?b:c evaluates to b if a is true, I'm getting an error in the a part.

Comment: You're mixing up conditional statements and ternary operators.

Comment: You seem to mix the plain [`if ... else` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if) with the [conditional (or ternary) operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
num % 2 == 0 ? printf("Number is even") : printf("Number is odd");
```

or:

```
if (num % 2 == 0) printf("Number is even") else printf("Number is odd");
```

Comment: So just to add: In ternary operation in the evaluation part we don't use a conditional if there must be an expression.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator, also known as shorthand if-else statement , it only needs a condition , no keywords and checks a condition and based upon the condition, executes the first block if the condition evaluates to true , else, evaluates the other part, when the given condition is false.
consider :

`(10>12) ? printf("condition is true!") : printf("condition is false!");`

you must not include any conditional keywords as the mix up of ternary and if-else is bound to throw error!
Also, Unlike if-else statements, you cannot leave the  ' else part ' in the ternary operator blank!
example - `(10>2) ? printf("condition is true!") : /*___blank__*/ ;`
it will give you an error saying, missing expression.
whereas , using if-else statements, you can do so!